# Decoding of codes generated from shannon fano encoding algorithm

Tags: c++, cryptography, compression

I have generated the codes for different symbol in a file using shannon fano algorithm.
Now my problem is that how i will store these codes into file (as file is in byte) so that while reading, reader can assure that at some point, it is the end of code for a particular symbol. So that extra code will not be read.

Comment: As far as I remember in Fano's code. The code of one symbol can't be prefix of another one. So there is no need of special delimiter, and you can just put sequence of bits to file (i.e. write to binary file).

Answer (score 3):

First, you can use bitwise operations to read a variable number of bits (not multiple of 8) from a byte array.

Second, if the code is a valid [Prefix code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code), which satisfies

```
there is no valid code word in the system that is a prefix (start) of any other valid code word in the set
```

then you can determine where the code ends by comparing the prefix with a table.

---

Usually, this is done in the following manner:

- Suppose the code length is anywhere from 1 to 16 bits.
- Load the next 16 bits from the file to the variable.
- Compare the 16-bit variable with a table which contain the following values. Binary search or radix search can be used.

  - Key: the Shannon-Fano or Huffman code, shifted so that the top bit is at the most-significant bit.
  - KeyLength: the actual number of bits in the Shannon-Fano or Huffman code. This allows us to subtract the number of decoded bits from the variable.
  - Value: the value that the code will decode to.
- Subtract (remove) the decoded bits from the variable depending on the code. For example, if the code has 9 bits, we will remove 9 bits from the MSB and keep the remaining 7 bits.
- Read the next 9 bits from the file, concatenating with the undecoded 7 bits.
- Repeat the process.

Comment: can we do some kind of bit stuffing while writing

Comment: mind the fact that the decoding loop should terminate when we know that decoded all the characters, so take into account a residual bit count